# Psr-4 composer autoload own class - no found

Tags: php, namespaces, composer-php, autoload

I have structure directory

[image]

autoload composer:

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
    "model\\": "src/"
  }
},
```

my class

```
namespace model;


class ClientAgent
{
    private $pdo;

    public function __construct(\PDO $pdo)
    {
        $this->pdo = $pdo;
    }

    public function sentAgent()
    {

    }
}
```

in `index.php` i tried add

`use model\ClientAgent;` but it throw error, not found class? why?

**Edit after answer**

```
     "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
       "model\\": "src/model/"
      }

  },
```

my index.php

```
use model\ClientAgent;

$loader=require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$clientAgent =new  ClientAgent($pdo);
```

error
 Uncaught Error: Class 'model\ClientAgent' not found in C:\xampp\htdocs\Wieloagenty\index.php:15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My suggestion is to introduce a vendor prefix. That might be your developer name, the name of your company or the name of the application.

`composer.json`

```
"autoload": {
  "psr-4": {
   "YourApplication\\": "src/"
  }
},
```

Now, every class inside the `src` folder and below needs this vendor prefix on it's namespace.

Let's take `src\model\ClientAgent.php` as example:

```
namespace YourApplication\Model;

class ClientAgent
{
```

Now, the FQCN (full qualified class name) is `YourApplication\Model\ClientAgent` and you might use it as part of a `use` statment.

```
// first require the Composer autoloader
require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

// declare which other classes you are using
use YourApplication\Model\ClientAgent;

$clientAgent = new ClientAgent($pdo);
```

**Important!**

After the modifications (to classes and the `composer.json` file) please regenerate the Composer autoloader with `php composer.phar dumpautoload -o`.

Composer will scan the complete `src` folder including subfolders for classes (so you'll have all classes from `src\models\` and `src\views` autoloading ready).

Answer (score 0):

`"model\\": "src/"` will give you the folder `src/` as the base for the `model`-namespace. So this would give you `model\model\Classname`.

Change it to:

```
"psr-4": {
    "model\\": "src/model/"
}
```

When defining psr-4 autoloader in composer, you associate a folder with a specific namespace.

Any sub folders will be a sub-namespace. So if you create a folder in your "model"-folder, the namespace would be: `model\new-foldername\Classname` and so on.

**Note:** When ever you update your composer.json file, you always need to run the command: `composer dump-autoload` to make composer regenerate all it's cached files.

Comment: Did you run: `composer dump-autoload` after changing composer.json? If not, you need to do it so composer regenerate it's autoload-file.

Comment: @Pablos - Not sure you got any notification about my comment (forgot to reference you). :)